# Character sprite will not react to keyPressed event

Tags: java, swing, input

So, I'm writing a small game. I have a JPanel inside of a JFrame and the JFrame repaints in the game engine class every frame, but the player sprite will not react to keypress events.

Any help?
Oh, I'm not entirely sure what code to post because I can't seem to find the source of the problem in any way so just tell me what code you wish to see.

Run method in the engine:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / 60D;

    int ticks = 0;
    int frames = 0;

    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0;

    init();

    while (engineRunning) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;
        boolean shouldRender = true;

        while (delta >= 1) {
            ticks++;
            tick();
            delta -= 1;
            shouldRender = true;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (shouldRender) {
            frames++;
            render();
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
            lastTimer += 1000;
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Tick & render in engine class:

```
public void tick() {
    for (BaseEntity e : worldEntities) {
        e.tick();
    }
}

public void render() {
    frame.repaint();
}
```

Player tick:

```
public void tick() {
    Position.X += Position.velX;
    Position.Y += Position.velY;

    if (Position.velX > Max_Speed) 
        Position.velX = Max_Speed;
    if (Position.velY > Max_Speed) 
        Position.velY = Max_Speed;
}
```

Comment: Using `KeyListener` right?  I wouldn't have to ask if your provided a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, but... Okay, instead of `KeyListener`, you should use the key bindings API which over comes the issues with `KeyListener`, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which is the advice given to all Swing/key events aren't working questions and forgive me if we haven't said this a million times before

Comment: You might start with a more elaborate description on how the player sprite should react as well as some code that links the character to the events and how the sprite is rendered (I assume the most important part would be the position/orientation of the character).

Comment: I'm using KeyAdapter, but I suppose I could try Key Bindings.

Comment: You want key events to work without a bunch of unreliable hacks, key bindings is your best choice

Comment: Added some code to the main post.

Comment: *"Added some code.."*  Why?  Or rather, why not add the *form of code* suggested by @MadProgrammer?  I've voted to close since a group of uncompilable code snippets does not make for a [mcve].